# Creating array from translated datas and merging an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I'm designing a site with multi-language support. Our main language is Turkish. I do not want while admin is inserting Turkish data, empty other fields in foreign languages. So when the Turkish data insert in ends with "_tr" columns, in the foreign language fields ends with "_en" and "_de", I want to get from Yandex Translator data which is automatically translated.
Here is my table structure:
[image]

My data structure like this which will be inserted:

```
$data = array(... 'parent_id' => 234, 'date' => "2014-08-31 23:07:47", 'status' => 1);
```

I want to to add in "..." like this:

```
$translated = array('fruit_tr' => "Elma", 'fruit_en' => "Apple", 'fruit_de' => "Apfel", 'color_tr' => "Kırmızı", 'color_en' => "Red", 'color_de' => "Rot");
```

I tried this:

```
$from_turkish = array('fruit' => "Elma", 'color' => "Kırmızı");

public function Translate ($from_turkish) { 
    $langs = array("tr", "en", "de");
    $translated = array();
    foreach ($langs as $lang){
        foreach ($from_turkish as $field_name => $value) {
            $translated[] = array($field_name.'_'.$lang => YandexTrApi($value, 'tr', $lang));   
        }
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

`YandexTrApi` function returns translated data. Finally, I used `array_merge` function like this:

```
$data_array = array_merge($translated, $data);
```

But it did not take form like this:

```
$data_array = array('fruit_tr' => "Elma", 'fruit_en' => "Apple", 'fruit_de' => "Apfel", 'color_tr' => "Kırmızı", 'color_en' => "Red", 'color_de' => "Rot", 'parent_id' => 234, 'date' => "2014-08-31 23:07:47", 'status' => 1);
```

Comment: Why not have a column for default and make sure it is always populated? Then on query if preferred language column is empty, fall back to default?

Comment: @Anthony - When we have default column like `fruit`, `color` then populate like `fruit_en`, `color_en`, it causes problem retriving data. Because when using `$lang->selected` like `$row["fruit{$lang->selected}"]`, program searchs `fruit_tr` but there is not. On the other hand there is no practical benefit coding like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_merge($translated, $data)` is fine and `$translated + $data` would give the same result in this case, but...

```
$translated[] = array($field_name.'_'.$lang => YandexTrApi($value, 'tr', $lang));
```

...this way you'll push new arrays inside `$translated` array. You need to add new keys only - try this instead:

```
$translated[$field_name.'_'.$lang] = YandexTrApi($value, 'tr', $lang);
```

Also the `foreach()` loops nested like this will give you slightly different order, but I guess you don't need it to match db (as your `...` part may be placed before `parent_id` key).

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I noticed. It is good solution for myproblem.